# Instantiate superclass variable in Java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have an abstract class which contains a variable 'name' that I want my child classes to initialize. Which of these would be the best way to do so.

#### Option 1. Use superclass constructor for initialization

```
    @Getter
    abstract class A {

      private final String name;

      protected A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

    }

    class B extends A {

      private static final NAME = "Raylan";
      private final int age;

      public B(int age) {
        super(NAME);
        this.age = age;
      }

    }
```

#### Option 2. Use a getter method.

```
    abstract class A {

      private final String name;

      public abstract String getName();

    }

    class B extends A {

      private static final NAME = "Raylan";
      private final int age;

      public B(int age) {
        this.age = age;
      }

      @Override
      public String getName() {
        return NAME;
      }

    }
```

Comment: Where is `getName` in the first example?

Comment: You can not force subclasses to instantiate a type. You can only enforce the implementation of methods (behavior). But not how they should implement those methods. So you can indeed force the implementation of some getter method like `getFoo()` but not the actual `foo` variable itself.

Comment: I've added a @Getter annotation.

Comment: @Zabuza I thought the `final` declaration forces the constructor to set the value once and only once.

Comment: @DavidKnipe It does. If something is declared `final` it can only be set once. Depending on the scope (for example for member variables) this needs to be done in the constructor in order to ensure that the variable can't be set elsewhere again. Why do you address this to me, what did I say that confused you?

Comment: I said "_once_ and only once" (emphasis added). Meaning that the constructor for `B` would be forced to set the value of `name`. (Which I've just realised it can't do if `name` is private.) But if I'm right then it contradicts your claim that "You can not force subclasses to instantiate a type.".

Answer (score 0):

Having a private `name` in `A` without a way to access it is useless.  Assuming a fully functional `getName()` in `A`, consider multiple constructors in `B`:

```
class B extends A {
  private static final String NAME = "Raylan";
  private final int age;

  public B(String name, int age) {
    super(name);
    this.age = age;
  }

  public B(int age) {
    this(NAME, age);
  }

  public int getAge() {
     return age;
  }

}
```

This allows re-use of `A`, otherwise there doesn't seem much point in `B` extending `A`.  Composition, instead of inheritance, could be another option.